# PHP session is not ending if session ID is passed via URL (with encryption) instead of cookie

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Due to some users who keep cookies disabled in their browsers and to keep my clients from getting bothered by it, I tweaked the PHP code to send session IDs via URL however, in encrypted form and with extra layers of security checks so, security is not an issue here. The issue is that even after destroying and unsetting the session, a page that requires session variable validation, still works fully, if it is visited with the same URL.

I am unsetting and destroying the session with the code as below. The variable $session_id is the one that stores the session id after decryption. Please advise.

```
session_id($session_id);
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
```

Comment: Not reproducible for me,  destroying a session immediately removes all session data, even if using the same ID, the session data will be empty on the next load.   Sounds like either you're destroying the wrong session or your check is invalid.

Comment: I checked thoroughly, session ID is same and check is valid. It works perfectly when used with cookies enabled in the browser.

Comment: Which tells me that the problem is with your $session_id variable or session_id call.  What debugging have you actually done here?

Comment: Now to check whether session id is same everywhere or not, I made the program to log session id for every page that it opens, including during logout and it logged the same session id for every page during a session, which confirms that session id that the programs carries forward until the user logs out, is same. Now, one thing that I noted is that after I logout, and open a page with session id (encrypted) in the URL, the program doesn't log session id like it does before logout. This might be a clue to cause of the issue.

Comment: To my understanding, it seems like browser is keeping exact copy of everything and displaying without fetching anything from the server but it is very strange because validation requires session variables and they are retained by the browser but not in the server end, most likely.